# Вычисление символа Якоби

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Не получается написать правильную реализацию алгоритма вычисления символа Якоби J(Q/P). Сначала сам алгоритм:

Вход: `Q`, `P` - целые числа.

Выход: значение символа Якоби.

1) s = 0, u = Q, v = P.

2) Вычисляем `r` - наименьший положительный остаток при делении `u` на `v`. Вычисляем целое `k >= 0` и нечетное `t`, такие, что `r = t * 2^k`. Вычисляем `s = s + k * (v^2 - 1)/8 + (t - 1)*(v - 1)/4 (mod 2)

3) Если `t = 1`, то символ Якоби равен `(-1)^s`. Конец.

4) Если `t >= 3`, то `u = v`, `v = t`, переходим на шаг 2.

Реализация:

```
#include <iostream>

int jacobi(int q, int p)
{
    int s = 0, u = q, v = p;
    int r, k, t;
    do{
        // Вычисляем r - наименьший положительный остаток при делении u на v
        r = u % v;
        // Вычисляем целое k >= 0 и нечетное t: r = t * 2^k
        k = t = 0;
        while(r % 2 == 0)
        {
            k++;        // Показатель степени двойки в числе r
            r >>= 1;    // Делим r на 2
        }
        t = r;          // В t находится результат деления r на 2^k
        s = (s + k * (v*v - 1)/8 + (t - 1)*(v - 1)/4) % 2;
        if(t == 1)
            return (s) ? 1 : -1;
        // Новая итерация
        u = v;
        v = t;
    }while(t >= 3);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << jacobi(-104, 997) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь J(-104, 997) должен быть равен -1, а моя реализация выдает 1.

Еще тесты из хелпа Maple: `jacobi(12, 3) = 0`, `jacobi(28, 21) = 0`, `jacobi(6, 11) = -1`, `jacobi(226, 135) = 1`, `jacobi(26, 35) = -1`, `jacobi(-286, 4272943) = 1`, `jacobi(888, 1999) = -1`.

**Дополнение:** в тернарном выражении я ошибся. Если s == 1 (true), то надо возвращать -1, потому что показатель степени нечетный.

Может быть, математики что-то дополнят?

Comment: https://ideone.com/KR5dW5

Comment: @Abyx, нормально - это как? И ошибок компиляции там нет.

Comment: @Abyx, в CLion достаточно современный компилятор, чтобы даже автоматически подставлять return'ы. Хотя поставить в самом деле не помешает. Видимо, при корректных входных данных этот алгоритм всегда приходит к единственному return'у, поэтому в псевдокоде другого выхода из процедуры нет.

Comment: "без однобуквенных переменных" Ну и как же вы назвали бы переменную t, в которой хранится результат деления числа на степень двойки? Rezultat_delenija_na_stepen_dvoiki? Пора привыкнуть, что математических алгоритмах дать осмысленные названия переменным чаще всего нельзя.

Comment: @Abyx, я вычислил много символов Якоби вручную через его свойства (и их не 8, а 4, если сгруппировать похожие), и этот алгоритм для меня все равно выглядит магическим. При ручном счете мы либо раскладываем один символ на произведение нескольких, каждый из которых вычисляем, либо применением закона взаимности сводим к тривиальным случаям, когда в числителе -1, 1 или 2. Если в числителе квадрат, то символ равен единице, поскольку является произведением двух равных символов. Зачем там выделять степень двойки - все равно непонятно.

Comment: А, ну то есть это мы извлекаем тривиальные символы с числителем 2. Тогда что вычисляется в выражении s? Поправка: почему оно так вычисляется? Видимо, это минус единица в некоторой степени при применении квадратичного закона взаимности.

Answer (score 1):

А давайте [книжку](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj73oGnxIPLAhUMCywKHTaGC7EQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frh.ddns.is74.ru%2FShares%2F%25D0%2594%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D0%25B3%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B5%2F%25D0%2594%25D0%25BE%25D0%25BA%25D1%2583%25D0%25BC%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D1%2586%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%2F_%25D0%2594%25D1%2580%25D1%2583%25D0%25B3%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B5%2F%25D0%2592%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B3%25D1%2580%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%2520-%2520%25D0%25A2%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25B8%25D1%258F%2520%25D1%2587%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BB.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHxnY7-xoHLni14O2V3vikl8Iw4Mg&sig2=_HYX1leLGAzk6RCiB7ImRw&bvm=bv.114733917,d.bGg) откроем.

### Свойства символа Якоби

Для *нечётного* **P > 1**:

1. **J(a, P) = J(a % P, P)**
2. **J(1, P) = 1**
3. **J(-1, P) = (-1)<sup>(P-1)/2</sup>**
4. **J(ab..l, P) = J(a, P) J(b, P) ... J(l, P)**, cледствие: **J(ab<sup>2</sup>, P) = J(a, P)**
5. **J(2, P) = (-1)<sup>(P<sup>2</sup> - 1) / 8</sup>**

Для *положительных нечётных взаимно простых* **P** и **Q**:

6. **J(Q, P) = (-1)<sup>(P-1) (Q-1) / 4</sup> J(P, Q)**.

Ни в алгоритме, ни в программе я не вижу даже намёков ни на анализ знаков, ни на факторизацию.
Т.е. основная используемая формула выглядит **недоказанной**.

Также известно, что символ Якоби **J(a, P)** - это **+1** или **-1**, поскольку *определён* для всех **a**, *не делящихся* на **P**. Поэтому *нулевой* результат по тесту Maple нуждается в специальной трактовке - например, для **J(12,3)**.